# Unable to compile using make test in Linux

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, command-line

While trying to compile my test plugin I encounter this error, for the moment I can't figure out why, last week I had some issues on windows but eventually solved them via OSGeo Shell but this time what should I do?

I typed in prompt: *make test* and got:

```
pyrcc4 -o resources_rc.py  resources.qrc
make: pyrcc4: Command not found
make: *** [resources_rc.py] Error 127
```

From the looks of it, I do not have the make command installed?

Comment: I tried to remove and install automake, also to install PyQt4-devel but I get the message: E: Unable to locate package PyQt4-devel.

Comment: Managed to install PyQt4-devel via another command line: sudo apt-get install pyqt4-dev-tools qt4-designer, so that I bump in into another issue: Compiled translation files to .qm files.
----------------------------------------
make: execvp: scripts/compile-strings.sh: Permission denied
make: *** [transcompile] Error 127

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get install pyqt4-dev-tools`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, found a way to solve the problem, but I'm not 100% sure if this is it or not.

After installing the PyQt4-devel, the next step would be to [source the file](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiwQ0SJYzJ8) (you can watch a nice tutorial done by Tim Sutton).

1. If you still have problems with the make file, try to run the "compile strings" file just like in the video.
2. Else if it doesn't work, then go to the qgis installation folder, go to the python plugin folder, open the properties of both compile strings and run-env-linux and tick the Execute.

After all those steps, make test (it should work now). How do I know that? Just try and call "python" into the terminal and type "import qgis.core", if you don't get any errors then it's all good.

3. Else, you might as well post your problem on gis stackexchange, and other QGIS places.

Hope it helps!